# Unable to add an attribute to an entry in OpenDJ LDAP

Tags: opendj, ldif

I am trying to add an attribute to a custom objectclass in OpenDJ, but am getting a reference error. I have checked the schema and can't see any reason why I shouldn't be able to add. Here is what I am trying to add:

```
dn: o=@!aaaa.bbbb.cccc.dddd!0001!eeee.ffff,o=myorg
objectClass: top
objectClass: myOrganization
managerGroup: inum=@!aaaa.bbbb.cccc.dddd!0001!eeee.ffff!0003!5555,ou=groups,o=@!aaaa.bbbb.cccc.dddd!0001!eeee.ffff,o=myorg
o=@!aaaa.bbbb.cccc.dddd!0001!eeee.ffff
```

When I try add it, I get the following (with long inums replaced with `...` for simplicty of this quote):

```
The DN "inum=...,ou=groups,o=...,o=myorg" could not be parsed due to the following reason: No attribute type with name or OID "inum" exists in the schema.
```

However, I can add an `inum` attribute to the the object (e.g. if I create the object without a `managerGroup` attribute, so inum is a known attribute. Here's the LDIF (in `config/schema/101-myorg.ldif`):

```
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.48710.1.3.117 NAME 'inum'
  DESC 'XRI i-number'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
  X-ORIGIN 'internal attribute' )
objectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.48710.1.4.4 NAME 'myOrganization'
  SUP ( top )
  STRUCTURAL
  MUST ( objectclass )
  MAY ( c $ county $ description $ ... $ inum $ managerGroup $ ... $ o $  ... )
```

I am able to add an entry with objectClass `myOrganization` and a `managerGroup` set to `ou=groups....,o=myorg` which adds fine. If I modify the entry to include an `inum` in the value, I get the error.

I have another install (that was run by a 3rd party installer script) which works fine with adding the entry, and I have compared the full schema across both installs, but cannot see any differences in the 2 installs. Yet behaviour changes. Is there anything I am overlooking? How can I resolve this to add the entry?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this could be an issue with schema order, I had an issue in the past where I had added an attribute to an objectclass in one of the original schema files (say 01-config.ldif) but the attribute was defined in 99-user.ldif, I saw an error on startup saying the attribute did not exist, all because it needed to be loaded first.

Comment: It's possible (especially since the file is named 101-myorg.ldif, which makes it one of the first to be loaded), and there would be an error message at startup about missing schema.